# how do i set UItableView datasource from CoreData relationship.

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

My coredata relationship fetch request returns NSSet objects. How can I set this data for a tableview datasource since NSset in unordered set. I can convert the NSSet to NSArray , but will it return the data in same order.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple is clear](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CHDDFHBE) that "The order of the objects in the array is undefined."  So I would expect it could change.

I would recommend that you store the `allObjects` array into an instance variable and use that to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView()` and the other datasource methods.

You could also store your `NSFetchedResultsController` in an instance variable and safely use it like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var rows = 0
    if self.fetchedResultsController!.sections!.count > 0 {
        let sectionInfo = getSectionInfo(section)
        rows = sectionInfo!.numberOfObjects
    }
    return rows
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let sectionInfo = getSectionInfo(section)
    return sectionInfo!.name
}

func getSectionInfo(section: Int) -> NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo? {
    var sections: [AnyObject] = self.fetchedResultsController!.sections!
    if section < sections.count {
        let x = sections[section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return x
    }
    return nil
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController!.sectionForSectionIndexTitle(title, atIndex: index)
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return self.fetchedResultsController!.sectionIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifier")! as UITableViewCell

    // Use your own NSManagedObject class here...mine is Category
    let category = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Category
    return cell
}
```

Personally I have coded all of the above methods in a base class that I reuse so I can just implement the `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` in each new table view.  I posted [a copy on github](https://github.com/prohner/CoreDataTableViewController/blob/master/CoreDataTableViewController.swift) in case it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I have one doubt , will  allobjects()  method return the array in same order as it was added it NSSet.

Comment: I added the first paragraph.  `allObjects()` order is undefined so I would expect it can change.